# Minimax code of connect 4 to make best move

Tags: c, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I have recently tried to implement the minimax algorithm for connect 4, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. 
here is my `heuristic`, `AI` and `minimax` code. Complete code is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/010pspnw975zyor/g6.c?dl=0#). I don't know where is the problem that it can't make correct moves.

```
int heuristic(int s[6][7]) {
    int result = 0;
    int i, j;

    //check horizontals
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        for(j=0; j<=7-4; j++){
            if(s[i][j]!= 2 && s[i][j+1]!= 2 && s[i][j+2]!= 2 && s[i][j+3]!= 2)
                result++;
            if(s[i][j]!= 1 && s[i][j+1]!= 1 && s[i][j+2]!= 1 && s[i][j+3]!= 1)
                result--;
        }

    //check verticals
    for(i=0; i<=6-4; i++)
        for(j=0; j<7; j++){
            if(s[i][j]!= 2 && s[i+1][j]!= 2 && s[i+2][j]!= 2 && s[i+3][j]!= 2 )
                result++;
            if(s[i][j]!= 1 && s[i+1][j]!= 1 && s[i+2][j]!= 1 && s[i+3][j]!= 1 )
                result--;
        }

    return result;
}

int minimax(int board[R][C], int depth, int turn /*1 or 2*/) {
    int e;
    int col, best;
    int n;
    int player;
    if((e=endgame(board, player))) {
        if(e==3)
            return 0;
        if(e==turn)
            return 10000;
        else
            return -10000;
    }

    if(depth==0)
        return ((turn==1) ? heuristic(board) : -heuristic(board));

    best = -10000;

    for(col=0; col < 7; col++)     //check every move
        if(board[6-1][col]==0) {   //make sure column isn't empty
            put(board, col, turn);
            n = minimax(board, depth-1, 3-turn);
            if(turn==1) {
                if ( -n > best ) best = -n;
            } else { //turn==2
                if ( -n > best ) best = -n;
            }
            rmv(board, col);
        }

    return best;
}

int ai(int board[R][C], int depth) {
    int col, move;
    int n, val = -10000-1;

    for(col=0; col < 7; col++)
        if(board[6-1][col]==0) {
            put(board, col, 2);
            n = minimax(board, depth, 1);
            if ( -n > val ) {
                val = -n;
                move = col;
            }
            rmv(board, col);
        }

    return move;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code on dropbox you have:

```
void rmv(int board[6][7], int column) { 
    int i;
    for (i=R-1; i>=0; i--){
        if (board[i][column] != 0) {
            board[i][column] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no break in the loop, so every time you reverse a move you will delete **every** piece in that column.

In addition I think the coordinates are the wrong way round in the stalemate code:

```
for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    if(s[i][6-1]==0)
        return 0;
```

I think this should be:

```
for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    if(s[6-1][i]==0)
        return 0;
```

The endgame detection code also looks odd:

```
int player;
if((e=endgame(board, player)))
```

This is passing an uninitialized variable player into the endgame function which seems unlikely to be correct.

Comment: Thank you, After correcting them AI make  **almost** correct moves. Still there is some problem with checking for winner.

Comment: player is an uninitialized variable passed into the endgame function - as the other person has just moved, perhaps 3-turn would be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, in minimax  function `player` should be `turn`, It now works better. I work on endgame.

Comment: Is line 57  `while(!(e=endgame(board,turn))) ` the problem for not exiting the game?

Comment: Note that your endgame function only detects wins for the current player and so I would expect you to want to change turn into 3-turn in both line 57 and  line 257 (because the game has ended if the **previous** player managed to make a line)